# Replace in string with alternation

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace `##` with `<<` and `>>` with alternation. For example `abc##123##qwe##asd##` to `abc<<123>>qwe<<asd>>`. Of course I can read symbols one by one, check them, do the replace to `<<` if it's even time or to `>>` if it's odd time. But there is power collection of standard functions in Python so I wonder if I can use them to reduce my code.

Comment: `re.sub(r'##(.*?)##', r'<<\1>>', s)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thank you, I should learn some about regular expressins

Comment: Just to point out that avinash's answer is great for cases where you know you have even numbers of `##`s, but won't work for odd/unmatched hashes.

Comment: What if it ends in something other than "##"?

Comment: It's not `##$`, should be okay, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following statement to change only pair of `##` and leave non-matching `##` as it is

```
d = "abc##123##qwe##asd"
re.sub(r'(##)(.*?)(?(1)##)', r'<<\2>>', d)

# 'abc<<123>>qwe##asd'
```

or you can do this

```
re.sub(r'(##)(.*?)(?(1)##)', r'<<\2>>', d).replace("##","<<")

# 'abc<<123>>qwe<<asd'
```